# VBA Insert Line After Data Change and Sum Data Group

Tags: vba, excel

I have a client with a long report of data that I am writing a VBA script to simplify.  What they would like is *after* each group of clients, a blank row is inserted. This is satisfied by:

```
Dim lRow As Long
For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
    If Cells(lRow, "C") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "C") Then Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
Next lRow
```

Now, in this empty row, I need an AutoSum of the values in Column F for the preceding group (i.e. the data leading to the blank row).

I've been trying to use the blank special cell type but can't seem to get anything to work.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could the `Auto Outline` Feature under `Data>Group>Auto Outline` be of help to you? If that does what you want it to manually, it could be adapted to code. Not sure yet what your data structure looks like.

Comment: @rohrl77 I wasn't able to get Auto Outline to do anything, but I haven't had much experience with that function.  I've attached a screenshot of the data structure for reference above. Thanks!

Comment: It appears that you are basically reinventing the Data- Subtotals feature which does exactly this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone looking for the VBA answer to this, the below worked for me:

```
Range("A1").Subtotal GroupBy:=3, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(6), _
    Replace:=False, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
```

*Group by is the column number of what the data is being grouped by. 
**The number in parentheses next to Array is the column that the preceding function is being applied to.

Thanks to @Rory for the inspiration.